# Queue Depth and vSCSI controllers

Tags: sql-server, performance, vmware

We have a purestorage san, a couple of VMhosts each serving up several SQL Server VM's. Each VMhost is given a slice of the SAN and each SQL Server VM is presented a single data VMDK and a single log VMDK.

Some SQL Servers have like 50+ databases. Each SQL Server VM is presented 1 single vSCSI controller.

Can adding a second vSCSI and creating another drive improve performance by increasing Queue Depth?

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you read the [VMware / SQL Server best practices guidelines](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf).

This is taken from that document:

> Utilize the VMware Paravirtualized SCSI (PVSCSI) Controller as the virtual SCSI 
>   Controller for data and log VMDKs. The PVSCSI Controller is the optimal SCSI 
>   controller for an I/O-intensive application on vSphere allowing not only a higher I/O 
>   rate but also lowering CPU consumption compared with the LSI Logic SAS. In addition, 
>   the PVSCSI adapters provide higher queue depth, increasing I/O bandwidth for the 
>   virtualized workload.
>
> Use multiple PVSCSI adapters. VMware supports up to four (4) adapters per a VM and 
>   as many as necessary, up to this limit, should be leveraged. Placing OS, data, and 
>   transaction logs onto a separate vSCSI adapter optimizes I/O by distributing load 
>   across multiple target devices and allowing for more queues on the OS level. Consider 
>   distributing disks between controllers. vSphere 6.7 supports up to 64 disks per 
>   controller

VMDK disk files have their own queue, with 64 entries, by default.  PVSCSI adapters have a default queue length of 256 per PVSCSI adapter, however [those settings can be modified](https://blogs.vmware.com/apps/2015/07/queues-queues-queues-2.html).